# Delete Duplications When Importing

Tags: vba, import, excel-2010

I'm doing this code for the company where I work as a internship. I did some part of it with the help of people from this forum and others but the code is big and I cannot find a place or the piece of code needed to do what I asked for, and that fits my code I'm newbie by the way.

So I will explain the code IT will import from a target excel file and then paste in my main file, after that it will search in the main file for the data that is present in the column A and then copy the information that is linked to the names and paste it in the import sheet called (Status) so I wanted to put a delete duplications before searching the information in the main file.

Sorry for the Big code. Forgot to mentioned the files come duplicated from the source file but I cannot change the source file, probably is easier if the import doesn't take duplicated rows ?

```
Sub ImportData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Path As String, Lstrw As Long
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook

Path = "C:\Users\DZPH8SH\Desktop\Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls"    'Change this to your company workbook path
workbook path
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set TargetWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim n As Integer, targetRow As Long
targetRow = 3

With SourceWb.Sheets(1)
    Lstrw = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    .Range("M1:M" & Lstrw).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="496"
    .Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw)).Copy
    TargetWb.Sheets(7).Cells(TargetWb.Sheets(7).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .ShowAllData
End With

With SourceWb.Sheets(2)
    Lstrw = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    .Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw)).Copy
    TargetWb.Sheets(7).Cells(TargetWb.Sheets(7).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

SourceWb.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'====================================== Search in the main file code below 

On Error Resume Next

Dim CurrWk As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Integer
Dim myLRow As Integer
Dim myLCol As Integer
Dim F1 As Boolean
Dim f As Boolean

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set CurrWk = wb.Sheets(7)

LRow = LastRow(CurrWk)

For r = 3 To LRow

    f = False

    For Each wk In wb.Worksheets

        If wk.Name = "Status" Or wk.Name = "Gráfico_2015" Then GoTo abc 'Exit For
        If wk.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then GoTo abc 'Exit For

        myLRow = LastRow(wk)
        myLCol = LastCol(wk)

        For r1 = 3 To myLRow
            For c1 = 1 To myLCol
                If Trim(CurrWk.Cells(r, 1).Value) = Trim(wk.Cells(r1, c1).Value) Then
                    f = True
                    F1 = False
                    If wk.Name = "ÄA" Then
                        For I = 12 To 18
                            If wk.Cells(r1, I).Value = 1 Then
                                CurrWk.Cells(r, 6).Value = wk.Cells(2, I).Value
                                F1 = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next I
                    Else
                        For I = 14 To 20
                            If wk.Cells(r1, I).Value = 1 Then
                                CurrWk.Cells(r, 6).Value = wk.Cells(2, I).Value
                                F1 = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next I
                    End If
                    If F1 = False Then CurrWk.Cells(r, 6).Value = "Set de equipa diferente"
                End If
            Next c1
        Next r1
        'If f = True Then Exit For
abc:
    Next wk

    If f = False Then
        CurrWk.Cells(r, 12).Value = "Não está presente no ficheiro"
    End If

Next r

Set wk = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the macro recorder gives you when you do a remove duplicates on some fake data?

Comment: no I did not, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exploring this avenue...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx

Using the VBA side of Range.RemoveDuplicates instead of manually just doing Remove Duplicates from the Data ribbon.

Comment: I wanted to add this to my actual code if when importing the data would be duplicated it would delete the row.

Comment: I puted this in my code but it deletes all my format of the page.                                                                                   Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)